# Why implement the onClickListener instead of just setting the onClick attribute to a defined method in the Activity class?

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, event-handling

I understand professionals use the former to tailor the onClick method to their exact specification, but cant I just use the onClick attribute and specify the same desired actions within a method. 
i.e. [In xml file:] `onClick="doSomething"` & then 
[in MainActivity.java:]

```
public void doSomething(View view){
     //define and start intent 
     //Show a toast, etc 
 }
```

Why not just use the latter option? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not just use the latter option?

Go right ahead.

On bigger projects, it is unlikely that the activity will be managing the button directly:

- You might be using fragments, in which case the fragment is more likely to manage the button than is the activity
- You might be using MVP, MVVM, MVI, etc. GUI architectures, in which case some other "presenter" object is more likely to manage the button than is the activity
- You might be using the data binding framework, in which case you might still be using `android:onClick` in a layout resource, but directing the event to something other than the activity (e.g., a fragment, a presenter)
- And so on

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so,both are doing the same thing but using the onClickListener is a better choice ,you can set the listener when you want that button to be active thus your Button and Activity are in cooordinaton.
If you use onClick in your xml file ,it will always call that method doesn't matter what is happening in your activity.